# How to add Link_to to an Uploaded Thumbnail

Tags: ruby-on-rails, image, hyperlink, indexing, paperclip

I'm trying to figure out the syntax to turn an uploaded project thumbnail in Ruby on Rails via Paperclip into a clickable link which leads to the projects details:

projects\index.html.erb

```
<% @projects.each do |project| %>

<%= image_tag (project.thumbnail.url(:small)) %>
<%= project.project_name %>
<%= project.project_city %>
<%= project.project_country %>

<%= link_to 'Show', project %>
```

Basically its adding the <%= link_to 'Show', project %> to the image_tag, but after trying a few iterations for the path I'm a bit stuck...

Thanks in advance

Comment: possible duplicate of [ruby on rails link\_to an image](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18484543/ruby-on-rails-link-to-an-image)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood you correctly, this is what you want:

```
<%= link_to project do %>
  <%= image_tag project.thumbnail.url(:small) %>
<% end %>
```