# ruby on rails link_to an image

Tags: ruby-on-rails, image, link-to

I'm facing the following problem: I have a very small image gallery with image files located in the following directories

```
 app/assets/images/locale/thumbs/
 app/assets/images/locale/big/
```

I have to create a hyperlink that as a content has a thumb image and as a target - its bigger version from **app/assets/images/locale/big/** folder:

```
<a href="path-to-full-size-image-001.jpg">
 <img alt="first photo preview" src="/assets/locale/thumbs/001.jpg" />
</a>
```

I'm doing this by means of

```
= link_to(image_tag("locale/thumbs/001.jpg"),  "locale/big/spizzicaluna001.jpg")
```

In fact I have tried many variants for the second argument of **link_to** but with little success - the bigger file can not be found.

How to resolve this issue?

Comment: when you click the thumbnail, what's happening?  do you get an error or just no picture?  if an error, what?

Comment: Please put your bigger file in public folder(then access it "http://youwebsit/spizzicaluna001.jpg" ) and then in link to point it

Comment: thanks! I put them into public folder and access them as "spizzicaluna001.jpg" from link_to.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

There are two approches to this issue.

1. You must specify the assets folder in the path.

   > link_to( image_tag("locale/thumbs/001.jpg"), 
   >   "/assets/locale/big/spizzicaluna001.jpg" )
2. Use an image path allowing rails to find the correct image

   > link_to( image_tag("locale/thumbs/001.jpg"),  image_path(
   >   "locale/big/spizzicaluna001.jpg") )

More info on image_path:

http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/AssetTagHelper/image_path

Comment: I think your #2 answer is "the answer".

Comment: Thanks a lot! **image_path** is what I needed!