# Rails - Link a thumbnail image to a larger full image

Tags: ruby-on-rails, image, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm new to Rails and I'm trying to decipher how to link an image to open a different image (thumbnail vs large image, and they aren't the same).

I've tried:

```
    <%= link_to "fullNews.jpg" do %>
      <% image_tag("smallNews.jpg", :alt => "Newsletter Preview", class: "grow shadow") %>
    <% end %>
```

As well as trying to use erb inside of erb:

```
    <%= link_to "<% image_tag("fullNews.jpg") %>" do %>
      <% image_tag("smallNews.jpg", :alt => "Newsletter Preview", class: "grow shadow") %>
    <% end %>
```

Even a direct link:

```
    <%= link_to "assets/images/fullNews.jpg" do %>
      <% image_tag("smallNews.jpg", :alt => "Newsletter Preview", class: "grow shadow") %>
    <% end %>
```

I'm sure it's just a syntax thing but I can't figure out how to achieve this?

Comment: this is possible a duplicate -> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18484543/ruby-on-rails-link-to-an-image

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pretty easy:

```
<%= link_to image_url("fullNews.jpg") do %>
      <%= image_tag("smallNews.jpg", :alt => "Newsletter Preview", class: "grow shadow") %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Perfect. Much appreciated. I knew I was close but I'm new to the Rails syntax.