# rails images load from public folder, but not from images

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, image, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm a beginner trying to to load some images in my rails view. When I try to load an image from the images folder in assets, I'm getting a broken image icon on the view and seeing `ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/assets/images/pp1.JPG")` in the console. This doesn't happen when I load the image from the public folder. How could I go about calling the image from the images folder--is it the way I'm calling it with the `<a>` tag? Any clarification will be much appreciated!

What I have on the view is:

```
<% provide(:title, "Imágenes") %>
<div class="container">
  <h1>Imágenes</h1>
  <p>Clic en la imagen para abrir en una pestaña nueva.</p>
  <div class="gallery">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-lg-3">
        <a href="pp1.JPG" target="_blank">
          <img src="pp1.JPG" alt="alt 1" width="200px" class="img-thumbnail">
        </a>
      </div>
      <div class="col-lg-3">
        <a href="peppe2.jpg" target="_blank">
          <img src="peppe2.jpg" alt="alt 2" width="200px" class="img-thumbnail">
        </a>
      </div>
      <div class="col-lg-3">
        <a href="peppe3.jpg" target="_blank">
          <img src="peppe3.jpg" alt="alt 3" width="200px" class="img-thumbnail">
        </a>
      </div>
      <div class="col-lg-3">
        <a href="peppe4.jpg" target="_blank">
          <img src="peppe4.jpg" alt="alt 4" width="200px" class="img-thumbnail">
        </a>
      </div>
    </div> <!---row1 ends -->

    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-lg-3">
        <a href="peppe5.jpg" target="_blank">
          <img src="peppe5.jpg" alt="alt 5" width="200px" class="img-thumbnail">
        </a>
      </div>
      <div class="col-lg-3">
        <a href="peppe6.jpg" target="_blank">
          <img src="peppe6.jpg" alt="alt 6" width="200px" class="img-thumbnail">
        </a>
      </div>
      <div class="col-lg-3">
        <a href="peppe7.jpg" target="_blank">
          <img src="peppe7.jpg" alt="alt 7" width="200px" class="img-thumbnail">
        </a>
      </div>
      <div class="col-lg-3">
        <a href="peppe8.jpg" target="_blank">
          <img src="peppe8.jpg" alt="alt 8" width="200px" class="img-thumbnail">
        </a>
      </div>
    </div> <!---row2 ends -->
  </div>
</div>
```

The first image (pp1.JPG) is in the images folder, and doesn't load; the others are in the public folder, and do load.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `image_tag` for this.  It will create the `<img src= ... >` bit for you.

To answer your question as to why your current code isn't finding the file, `image_tag` will prepend the `src` path with `/assets/` as the default, so you'll end up with something like `<img src='/assets/peppe3.png/'>`.  You can pass a file path to `image_tag` to override this if you wish.  More info: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/AssetTagHelper.html#method-i-image_tag

Comment: Thank for the help. I'm still not clear on how to combine the image_tag with the linking (I get how it replaces the src part in what I have, but not the href. Any thoughts will be well received.

Comment: @gonzalo2000 Try the #2 suggestion on this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/18487219/2599738.  You can pass `size`, `alt`, and `class` (along with other options) to `image_tag`.  The answer uses two different files (a thumbnail and a full-size), but if you keep your paths straight it should work.  Not sure if it's the best solution, but it should get you to a point where it's working and you can more easily experiment with alternatives.

Comment: Thank you for the reference! This took care of it (I decided I didn't really need the alt in this context): `<%= link_to(image_tag("peppe5.jpg", width: '200', class: "img-thumbnail"), image_path("peppe5.jpg"), target: '_blank') %>`

Answer (score 1):

HTML

```
<div class="col-lg-3">
  <%= link_to image_path('pp1.JPG'), target: '_blank' do %>
    <%= image_tag('pp1.JPG', alt: 'alt 1', class: 'img-thumbnail my-class') %>
  <% end %>
</div>
...etc...
```

CSS

```
.my-class {
  width: 200px;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the hand. However, I still see the broken image icon, and I get a "Sorry, but something went wrong" in a new tab. The console says "ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/images/pp1.JPG")". Any ideas what could be going on?

Comment: I see, you've already found the solution! if it won't work in `production` after server deploying, your images in `public` is better solution than in `assets` and just do `rake assets:precompile`. and of course, you'll find much more useful advices on [rubyonrails.guides](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html)

Comment: Thank you, much appreciated!